# Tabel I over table

Tags: tables

[image]

How do I remove the ":" and make the table text to be like this? As just doing \begin {table} makes everything on the same line.

This is my table for now.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[h]
 \small
 \centering
 \caption{Simuleringsresultat av beräkning av $\pi$ genom Monte Carlo.}
 \begin{tabular}{|p{2.1cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{2.1cm}|p{2.1cm}| }
   \hline
   \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{En beräkning av $\pi$ genom Monte Carlo} \\
    \hline
Antal \linebreak partiklar & Värde 1 & Värde 2 & Värde 3 & Värde 4 &   Värde 5 & Medelvärde\\
 \hline
 $10^0$  & 4    & 4 &   4  & 4 & 0 & 3,2      \\
 $10^1$ & 3,2  & 2,4   & 4,0  & 3,6  & 3,6 & 3,36  \\
 $10^2$ & 3,56 & 2,92 &  3,32   &  3,04  & 3,36 & 3,24    \\
 $10^3$ & 3,208 & 3,160 &  3,108  & 3,136  & 3,136 & 3,1496  \\
 $10^4$ & 3,1404  & 3,1288 & 3,1460  & 3,1572 & 3,1308 & 3,14064  \\
 $10^5$ & 3,13468  & 3,14724   & 3,14316 & 3,14124  & 3,14248 & 3,14176     \\
 $10^6$ & 3,14286  & 3,146348 & 3,142648  &  3,141184  & 3,142144 & 3,1430368 \\
 $10^7$ & 3,1421208  & 3,141374 & 3,1414892  & 3,1413988  & 3,1416936 & 3,14161528 \\
 $10^8$ & 3,14138248  & 3,14127896 & 3,14172908  & 3,14154640 & 3,14178604 & 3,141544592 \\
 $10^9$ & 3,1416602762  & 3,1415840040 & 3,1415684520   &  3,1415948080 & 3,1416119840 & 3.1416039048   \\
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{$\pi = 3.1415926535 $ }  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which LaTeX document class you employ.

Comment: Thank you! So, added everything (might have missed some packages) that might be relevant :).

Comment: Do you just want to remove tha colon and instead add a linebreak between table number and caption text or do you also want the word "table"  to appear in all caps, while the caption text itself is in small caps?

Comment: Entirely unrelated, but are you aware, that your table is quite alot wider than the available textwith? You might want to address that issue as well.

Comment: Yeah, remove that colon and a linebreak between that and caption text. Table should be in all caps however the caption in regular text :)

Comment: Shouldn't \small solve that problem?

Comment: Regarding the caption: Adding `\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline, tablename=TABLE}` should do the trick. Regarding the table width: unless you changes the margin size in your actual document as compared to the MWE you included in your question, the table does not fit, even if you decrease the font size to small.

Comment: Please consider upvoting the answer if it was helpful. This is normal on this site. IN addition, consider accepting the answer if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you insert the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}
\renewcommand\tablename{TABLE}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,
              labelfont=up,
              textfont=sc,
              justification=centering,
              singlelinecheck=false}
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}
\renewcommand\tablename{TABLE}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,
              labelfont=up,
              textfont=sc,
              justification=centering,
              singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Simuleringsresultat av beräkning av $\pi$ genom Monte Carlo.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I honestly thought that this was also part of the question. I will swiftly remove my comment. And thx for the polite way of saying "it's BS" ;) (orthogonal)